# How to add HeaderView in UICollectionView like UITableView's tableHeaderView

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

How can I add a header view / top view (not section header) at the top of a `UICollectionView`?

It should act excactly as `UITableView`'s `tableHeaderView` property.

So it needs to sit on top of the first section header view (before the section at index 0), scroll along with the rest of the content, and have user interaction.

The best I've come up with so far is to make a special XIB (with `MyCollectionReusableView` subclass of `UICollectionReusableView` as the File's owner) for the first section header view that is big enough to also contain my subviews in header, it's kind of a hack, I think, and I haven't managed to detect touches.

Not sure if I can make my `MyCollectionReusableView` subclass to allow touches or there's a better way.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this situation? I am having the same problem

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've put a view at the top of a collection view by just adding a UIView as a subview of the collection view. It does scroll up with the collection view and it has normal UIView user interaction. This works ok if you have no section header, but doesn't work if you do. In that situation, I don't see anything wrong with the way you're doing it. I'm not sure why you're not detecting touches, they work fine for me.

Comment: Thanks, I do already use section headers, so the first one (section header at index 0) I've made bigger to contain both the standard section header and the view on top of the collection view. But you say you get touches inside your `MyCollectionReusableView` subclass?

Comment: Just went back and tried again, and you're right - it works! I had been working too late and I used `UIImageView`'s to detect touches and forgot to tick the "User Interaction Enabled" for my image views in Xcode.

Comment: How did you achieve this? I add it (it's a `UISearchBar` btw) to the collectionView (with constraints top, leading trailing) with required contentInset and it just shows a blank space at the top and in the view debugger it says collection view contentsize ambiguous.

Comment: I'm really stuck here. I'd really appreciate it if you could help me out.

Answer (score 63):

```
self.collectionView  =  [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, self.view.frame.size.height) collectionViewLayout:flowlayout];
self.collectionView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(50, 0, 0, 0);
UIImageView *imagev = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"015.png"]];
imagev.frame = CGRectMake(0, -50, 320, 50);
[self.collectionView addSubview: imagev];
[self.view addSubview: _collectionView];
```

I use the attribute `contentInset` to insert a frame to the top of the `UICollectionView`, then I add the image view to it, and it succeeds. I think it can act excactly as `UITableView`'s `tableHeaderView` property. What do you think?

Comment: I was searching for this, it's much better than making the first section header taller.

Comment: i have used above way for adding header vie ,Not able to get touch event on header view , any idea why ?

Comment: Thank you for this.

Comment: @arpan_techisavy because the view that you have adding is beyond it's superview.

Comment: Any way to add collectionFooterView?

Comment: It appears this doesn't work if you're supporting right to left languages. Subviews outside the collectionViews bounds won't be rendered correctly when switching to right to left layouts and will appear mirrored.

Answer (score 10):

Since iOS 13 a canonical way to set the header is to use `UICollectionViewCompositionalLayoutConfiguration`

This way allows setting `boundarySupplementaryItems` per section or globally for a collection view.

```swift
let headerSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0), heightDimension: .estimated(44))

let header = NSCollectionLayoutBoundarySupplementaryItem(layoutSize: headerSize, elementKind: "header", alignment: .top)

let config = NSCollectionViewCompositionalLayoutConfiguration()
config.boundarySupplementaryItems = [header]

let layout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout(sectionProvider: sectionProvider, configuration: config)

return layout
```

To learn more visit the official documentation at: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nscollectionviewcompositionallayoutconfiguration

Comment: Looks like NSCollectionViewCompositionalLayoutConfiguration (and even the link included in this answer) are MacOS only.

Comment: for UIKit it's UICollectionViewCompositionalLayoutConfiguration
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewcompositionallayoutconfiguration

Answer (score 5):

I ended up using a UICollectionView extension to add my custom header. Using a specific tag, I'm able to fake the stored property to identify my custom header (all transparent from outside). 
You might have to scroll to a specific offset if the layout of the UICollectionView is not completed when you add your custom header.

```
extension UICollectionView {
    var currentCustomHeaderView: UIView? {
        return self.viewWithTag(CustomCollectionViewHeaderTag)
    }

    func asssignCustomHeaderView(headerView: UIView, sideMarginInsets: CGFloat = 0) {
        guard self.viewWithTag(CustomCollectionViewHeaderTag) == nil else {
            return
        }
        let height = headerView.systemLayoutSizeFitting(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize).height
        headerView.frame = CGRect(x: sideMarginInsets, y: -height + self.contentInset.top, width: self.frame.width - (2 * sideMarginInsets), height: height)
        headerView.tag = CustomCollectionViewHeaderTag
        self.addSubview(headerView)
        self.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: height, left: self.contentInset.left, bottom: self.contentInset.bottom, right: self.contentInset.right)
    }

    func removeCustomHeaderView() {
        if let customHeaderView = self.viewWithTag(CustomCollectionViewHeaderTag) {
            let headerHeight = customHeaderView.frame.height
            customHeaderView.removeFromSuperview()
            self.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: self.contentInset.top - headerHeight, left: self.contentInset.left, bottom: self.contentInset.bottom, right: self.contentInset.right)
        } 
    }
}
```

CustomCollectionViewHeaderTag refers to the tag number you give to your header. Make sure it is not the tag of anotherView embedded in your UICollectionView.

Comment: This is really a nice workaround to resolve the conflict to section header!

Comment: This really, really, really helped me out. Amazing. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The best way to achieve this is to make a section header for the first section. Then set the UICollectionViewFlowLayout's property:

```
@property(nonatomic) BOOL sectionHeadersPinToVisibleBounds
```

or swift

```
var sectionHeadersPinToVisibleBounds: Bool
```

to NO (false for swift).  This will ensure that the section header scrolls continuously with the cells and does not get pinned to the top like a section header normally would.

Comment: this works for me , but what if I want some sectionHeader pinned to the top, but some not? this  UICollectionViewFlowLayout's property likes a global set.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to accomplish this it to subclass UICollectionViewLayout(UICollectionViewFlowLayout) and add the needed header or footer attributes.

Since all the items including the supplementary view in UICollectionView layout according to its `collectionViewLayout` property, it is the `collectionviewlayout` that decides whether there is a header(footer) or not.

Use `contentInset` is easier, but there may be problem when you want to hide or show the header dynamically.

I have written a protocol to accomplish this, which could be adopted by any subclass of UICollectionViewLayout to make it have a header or footer. You can find it [here.](https://github.com/Phelthas/LXMWaterfallLayout)

The main idea is to create a `UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes` for the header and return it in `layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect)` if needed, you will have to modify all the other attributes, all of their locations should be moved down by header height because the header is above them all.

Answer (score -2):

```
private var PreviousInsetKey: Void?
extension UIView {

var previousInset:CGFloat {
    get {
        return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &PreviousInsetKey) as? CGFloat ?? 0.0
    }
    set {
        if newValue == -1{
            objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &PreviousInsetKey, nil, .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC)
        }
        else{
            objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &PreviousInsetKey, newValue, .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC)
        }
    }
}


func addOnCollectionView(cv: UICollectionView){
    if self.superview == nil{
        var frame = self.frame
        frame.size.width = SCREEN_WIDTH
        cv.frame = frame
        self.addOnView(view: cv)
        let flow = cv.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
        var inset = flow.sectionInset
        previousInset = inset.top
        inset.top = frame.size.height
        flow.sectionInset = inset
    }

}

func removeFromCollectionView(cv: UICollectionView){
    if self.superview == nil{
        return
    }
    self.removeFromSuperview()
    let flow = cv.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
    var inset = flow.sectionInset
    inset.top = previousInset
    flow.sectionInset = inset
    previousInset = -1
}

func addOnView(view: UIView){

    view.addSubview(self)

    self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    let leftConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
    let widthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: view.frame.size.width)
    let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: view.frame.size.height)
    let topConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)

    view.addConstraints([leftConstraint, widthConstraint, heightConstraint, topConstraint])
    self.layoutIfNeeded()
    view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain what your solution is doing?