# Add header to UICollectionView, not to section of UICollectionView

Tags: ios, storyboard, uicollectionview

Similar functionality exists for `UITableView`. I can add a header to `UITableView` or for every section in that `UITableView`. Here the question is how to add header to `UICollectionView` programatically? Not to every section of `UICollectionView`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add HeaderView in UICollectionView like UITableView's tableHeaderView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13522075/how-to-add-headerview-in-uicollectionview-like-uitableviews-tableheaderview)

Answer (score -2):

```
- (UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (kind == UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader) {

        UICollectionReusableView *reusableview = [collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader withReuseIdentifier:@"HeaderView" forIndexPath:indexPath];

        if (reusableview==nil) {
            reusableview=[[UICollectionReusableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
          }

        UILabel *label=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
        label.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Recipe Group #%li", indexPath.section + 1];
        [reusableview addSubview:label];
        return reusableview;
      }
      return nil;
  }
```