# UICollectionView header view like table view header (not the section header)

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

Is it possible to create UICollectionView header view like UITableView headerView? I mean header view for whole collection view, not the repeated one for each section. Like the picture1 is I want, picture which is now i have done.

[image: PictureOne]

[image: PictureTwo]

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13522075/how-to-add-headerview-in-uicollectionview-like-uitableviews-tableheaderview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the solution now. Add a subview in the collectionView and make the collectionView contentInset below the topImageView like below.

```
    topImageView.frame = CGRect(x: 5*SCREEN_SCALE, y: -125*SCREEN_SCALE, width: 285*SCREEN_SCALE, height: 120*SCREEN_SCALE)
    collectionView.addSubview(topImageView)
    collectionView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 130*SCREEN_SCALE, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
```

Comment: But here scrolling is not applicable for topImageView, means when I scroll the collectionview topImageView do not scroll right.

Answer (score 0):

There's a workaround that I use when wanting to achieve this. When setting the header size, I check section number before setting it. If it's the first section, I set the height accordingly - otherwise I set the height to 0 so it isn't visible

```
   func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {

        if section == 0 {

            return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 35)
        } else {

            return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 0)
        }
    }
```

Comment: i think your answer is not fit to me. At First, I have both section header and the header to the whole collectionView. If there's no section header, maybe your answer can work. In the other time, there is not section parameter in this function. So...

Answer (score -1):

In swift like below

Register Header View

```
collectionView.registerClass(HeaderView.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "headerView")
```

In UICollectionViewDelegate

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {

     if section == 0 {
    let headerView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind(UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "headerView", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    headerView.frame.size.height = 100

    return headerView }

    else {
         return nil
   }
}
```

Important is that you are supply the flow layout with the header size

```
flowLayout.headerReferenceSize = CGSize(width: self.collectionView.frame.width, height: 100)
```

Otherwise the delegate method will not get called

Comment: i think your answer is not fit to me. At First, I have both section header and the header to the whole collectionView.  If there's no section header, maybe your answer can work. In the other time, there is not section parameter in this function. So...

Comment: @C.Hugh everything wont fit to our needs. We have to customize it as per our requirement. Explain what issue your getting will help.